How can i represent indirect relationship in class diagrams?
I am working on a system where:

A Customer can place an Order.
The Order goes into an OrderPool, which holds all unassigned orders.
A Volunteer picks orders from the OrderPool for delivery.

I’ve created a class diagram, but I’m unsure about the relationships between these entities and whether the design is optimal. Specifically.

Should I represent the interaction between Volunteer and OrderPool directly or indirectly via Order?

This comment doesn’t answer your question, but points out some problems that may prevent other people from copying them.
First, rather than have lists and associations, just use associations. Every binary association already has two end properties, which you haven’t bothered to name. When an end property has a max multiplicity more than one, it already is a collection.
Second, a term in guillemets on an association extends the UML language with a special kind of association, which is not what you want here. You want an association called places and an association called picks.

You should also tell us if this model is intended to be at the analysis level (which should have no design concerns like a pool) or at the detailed design level.

Also, an association is not a relationship, it is a relation or, roughly, a type of relationship. Instances of an association are called links or, roughly, relationships. (I say “roughly” because they’re actually mathematical tuples that signify relationships in the world.)

To decide on the proper way, you need to make the difference between behavioural and structural aspects of your design.
Simple temporary interactions (behavioural dynamics) between instances of a class do not require associations. Associations are for structural relationships that have a meaning beyond a simple operation or interaction.
Here the possible situations in your case for the pool:

the Volunteer picks from the Pool. In an interaction diagram you would show an exchange of messages between the two, where a Volunteer would request the Pool for the next Order. But this is behavioural and in a class diagram the two may remain unrelated.
If there are several Pools  and the Volunteers have to be assigned for some time to some Pool(s) to know where they can pick orders from, this becomes a structural relationship, and an association between Volunteer and Pool would make sense ("assignment").

And here for the volunteer and the order:

If your system needs to find back which Volunteer prepared which Order, then you need a structural ("semantic") relationship, and the association order/volunteer would be justified.
If the preparation is a lasting operation,  and you need to keep track of which orders are being prepared by whom at any time, it is also a structural relationship  and the association order/volunteer would again be justified.
If it is spurious, i.e the two are only related for performing an operation (behaviour) but there is no need track the state beyond "order in preparation" because the order is displayed on the screen of the volunteer, then there would be no need to keep association.

